# Is there any other pattern other than MVP and MVC?

Tags: java, android, iphone, ios, objective-c

MVP and MVC are mostly used patterns in Java and other languages. Is there any other list of patterns working like MVC and MVP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I cant speak for Java but with big iOS projects (often using Core Data) you normally expand the `MVC` pattern to `MVCS` (Model-View-Controller-Store). The `Store` is responsible for fetching data provided by external sources and providing data to controllers. You do this to not mess up your controllers in such projects.

But for normal projects `MVC` is your way to go.

Comment: Thanks Jorg for the answer.

Comment: @Mr.Khan Please care to vote someone if someone is helping you. And if you got the satisfied answer.